# Prevent loading data for the initial page when using server-side processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

Is there a way to prevent loading the rows for the initial page via `AJAX` when using `DataTables` with server-side processing?

When the page is loaded, the rows for the first page are already available in the `HTML`. I would like `DataTables` to use the rows already available in the `DOM` for the initial page. When sorting/searching/paging, the data to be shown must of course be loaded using `AJAX`, but this is not necessary for the initial page, in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`deferLoading`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferLoading) option which is there to delay the loading of server-side data until second draw. You just need to provide total number of records in your dataset.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",
  "deferLoading": 57
} );
```